# ffmpeg transcode video with dts-ma to ac3

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to take a video that has an h264 video track and a dts-ma audio track and and get out an .m4v file with:

h264 video track
DTS-ma audio track
AC-3 5.1 Audio track

I'm attempting to just copy the video and the dts-ma audio track and then have it convert the AC-3 audio track

I'm getting an error `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ac3'` from this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 -acodec ac3 -ac 6 -ab 448k -c:a:2 -acodec ac3 -ac 6 -ab 256 -ar 48000 "output.m4v"
```

(this is generated by my C# app)

this for a different file that has h264 and ac3 already in it works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy "output.m4v"
```

Obviously it's not doing a conversion.

Here's the full results of the first command:

```
ffmpeg version N-46936-g8b6aeb1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 20 2012 19:34:37 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass -
-enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libo
pus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-li
bvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52.  8.100 / 52.  8.100
  libavcodec     54. 74.100 / 54. 74.100
  libavformat    54. 37.100 / 54. 37.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 23.101 /  3. 23.101
  libswscale      2.  1.102 /  2.  1.102
  libswresample   0. 17.101 /  0. 17.101
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2012-12-07 22:11:56
  Duration: 01:41:23.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 33582 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 186.250000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0.1: start 186.250000, end 512.708000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:03:06.250
    Chapter #0.2: start 512.708000, end 883.292000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:08:32.708
    Chapter #0.3: start 883.292000, end 1354.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:14:43.292
    Chapter #0.4: start 1354.000000, end 1865.458000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:22:34.000
    Chapter #0.5: start 1865.458000, end 2122.500000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:31:05.458
    Chapter #0.6: start 2122.500000, end 2386.125000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:35:22.500
    Chapter #0.7: start 2386.125000, end 2801.167000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:39:46.125
    Chapter #0.8: start 2801.167000, end 2923.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:46:41.167
    Chapter #0.9: start 2923.000000, end 3388.500000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:48:43.000
    Chapter #0.10: start 3388.500000, end 3808.167000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:56:28.500
    Chapter #0.11: start 3808.167000, end 4071.375000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:03:28.167
    Chapter #0.12: start 4071.375000, end 4378.750000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:07:51.375
    Chapter #0.13: start 4378.750000, end 4681.583000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:12:58.750
    Chapter #0.14: start 4681.583000, end 4989.792000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:18:01.583
    Chapter #0.15: start 4989.792000, end 5311.667000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:23:09.792
    Chapter #0.16: start 5311.667000, end 5629.083000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:28:31.667
    Chapter #0.17: start 5629.083000, end 6083.382000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:33:49.083
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
[NULL @ 03f4b020] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ac3'
ac3: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please show the complete ffmpeg console output from your command that is not working as expected. Update your question with the console output (some people try to add it to comments).

Comment: Here's the full results:

Comment: I see no AC-3 audio stream in this input.

Comment: It's supposed to convert from TrueHD to AC-3. That's the point. I did a test and was able to get a *.ac3 stream from the TrueHD with no other options, just not make a new file copying the video, the audio and creating a new ac-3 stream at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably because of the addition of the parameter `-acodec`.

`-acodec` is an alias for `-codec:a` or `-c:a`.

Since you are already specifying the tracks with `-c:a:X`, you don't need the `-acodec` right after it.

This should work:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 ac3 -ac 6 -ab 448k -c:a:2 ac3 -ac 6 -ab 256 -ar 48000 "output.m4v"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now I'm getting "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: N/M just figured it out. FFMPEG thinks that m4v can't hold trueHD... now I just need to figure out how to get a DTS track from TrueHD

Comment: FYI for anyone as of right now FFMPEG doesn't allow TrueHD, DTS-Master, or DTS in m4v files even though the standard supports them.... I've filed a bug report with ffmpeg, hopefully it will get fixed so that you can encode to m4v with the advanced audio tracks!